# Linked-list Data Structure understanding

Tags: python, class, data-structures, linked-list

I have a little difficulty in understanding one thing in the structure of the Linked-lists.
Basically nodes of a linked list are created using the following class, and the next reference is obtained by the method getNext():
I have omitted other methods as not relevant to my problem.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,initdata):
       self.data = initdata
       self.next = None

    def getNext(self):
       return self.next
```

Now when creating a linkedlist and trying to find the size of the linked-list:

```
class UnorderedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current != None:
            count = count + 1
            current = current.getNext()    <-----

        return count
```

I do not understand the line shown with an arrow. I know the logic that it tries to traverse to the next node, but getNext() is the method of the "NodeClass". how is it (getNext() method) being used by an object (i.e. current) which is not a NodeClass object? and actually it is an object of the "UnorderedList" class.

Comment: Where is this code from?

Comment: What makes you think `current` is not a `Node` instance? `current = self.head`  sets `current` to whatever `self.head` is. If `self.head` is a `Node` instance, then so is `current`

Comment: but how self.head is a Node instance? it is used to initialize an UnorderedList class object!!!

Comment: @DanielLee you may find the explanation here
[link](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ImplementinganUnorderedListLinkedLists.html)

Comment: @SinaHwz - you have omitted from your example a crucial piece of code -- the code that sets assigns a non-`None` value to `self.head`. Surely that missing line of code sets `self.head` to a `Node` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current` is basically an instance of `UnOrderedList` in which each element is `Node` object. Hence the methods that are applied on `Nodes` can be applied on each element of `current`. Nodes are added to `UnOrderedList` using the add method.

```
def add(self,item):
    temp = Node(item)
    temp.setNext(self.head)
    self.head = temp
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, its clear but my issue is that `current` must be a node to be able to call `getNext()` method. I believe I have missed it somewhere to create a `node` out of `current` value

Comment: You are assigning it here `current = self.head` , now the current object becomes node

Comment: But the `node` object contains only two parts: `self.data` and `self.next` !

Comment: self.head is now part of UnorderedList object

Comment: When you create a `UnorderedList`, you say `mylist = UnOrderedList()` and add elements to it. And each element in UnorderedList is a node object.

Comment: Please check add method, it might clear your doubts.

Comment: Thats it.... i was missing the point, that every item will be turned to a `node` object before being added to the `list`
Thank you @v.coder

Comment: and please edit your answer to include the `add` method and that every item being added to the list will be converted to a `node` object first. thank you :)